# Is there any DAX expression to find out the results?

Tags: dax

As shown in images(link) that we have to count the no.of arrivals of a customer by cross checking with sessionStart. I need to represented the customer visits(count) based on the following trends: Once Every 3 Months / Once A Month / Once A Week / More Than Once A Week by using date field or (Session Start and Session End)?

[Table name EDW_KLOUDSPOT_TXS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiihv.png)
[Power Bi visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBJWm.png)

Comment: You can have a history table which stores required information whenever a customer visits along with the created/updated column. And then you can query accordingly with current date.

Comment: As of now you're request is too vague. We'll need to be able to see table structures and sample data to be able to provide a detailed answer.